# QGIS is not working if the Python script is running with infinite loop

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

While executing the following code, I'm getting the error in the QGIS Software window. Err: `"QGIS Desktop is not responding"`
If the same code executed in the standalone Python application and added a few new points in the QGIS layer then the `layer_details.dataProvider().featureCount()` value is not changing. It is not considering the new points.

```
import time
while (True):
  layer_details = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0]
  print (layer_details.dataProvider().featureCount())
  time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code will work on the QGIS Python console, but not on standalone.
since I want to use it on a standalone application so instead of the above code I'm using the python threading concept. and it's working perfectly fine.

```
def qgisThread():
     while(True):
         layer_details = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(<layer_name>)[0]
         for feature in layer_details.getFeatures():
             geom = feature.geometry()
             geomSingleType = QgsWkbTypes.isSingleType(geom.wkbType())
             if (geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PointGeometry):
                 if (geomSingleType):
                     x = geom.asPoint()
                     print("Point: ", feature["name"])
         time.sleep(15)
 
 
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     t1 = threading.Thread(target=qgisThread)
     t1.start()
     t1.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `time.sleep()` function blocks the thread from which it was invoked, so it is preventing the main thread from continuing to execute. You can find lots of information about this with an internet search.

Try the following instead. I have not tested in a standalone application but it is working for me in the Python console (feature count is printed every 10 seconds and newly added features are picked up in the count).

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

timer = QTimer()

def get_feature_count():
    l = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0]
    print(l.featureCount())
    
timer.timeout.connect(get_feature_count)
timer.start(10000) #milliseconds
```

*Execute the line: `timer.stop()` to stop the timer.

Also, I notice there seems to be some redundancy in the code in your question. It seems you have a layer object stored in the variable called `layer`. You then create a new layer object by passing the return value of the `.name()` method of the existing layer object.

If you already have a `QgsVectorLayer` object, the code above could be simplified to:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

timer = QTimer()

# QgsVectorLayer object
layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('layer_name_string')[0]

timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print(layer.featureCount()))

timer.start(10000)
```

Comment: working fine in qgis python console but not for the standalone.